# how to separate integer numbers from a string?

Tags: java, parsing

I have a string

```
String exp = "7 to 10";
```

now I am keeping a condition that

```
if (exp.contains("to"))
{
    // here I want to fetch the integers 7 and 10
}
```

How to separate 7 and 10 from the string `7 to 10` (parsed as `Integer`).

By using a delimiter I can obviously do it but I want to know how to do it this way?

Comment: does your string contains `spaces` ? `7 10` are values inside string not integers

Comment: You mean you don't want to use `String.split()`?

Comment: yeah the space is there coz the string is  "7 to 10".. @SanKrish

Comment: @suganya You can use `substring()` if it is a static string

Comment: Why don't you use regex? `(d+)\ to\ (d+)` will do it for you.

Comment: String.split() whill split like "7-10". but my string is "7 to 10"... @Tariq

Comment: @suganya split can split on any character/string.

Comment: @suganya split only works for - ?? try `split("to")` OR `split(" to ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code,

```
import java.io.*;

public class test
{
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input="7 to 10";//pass any input here that contains delimeter "to"
        String[] ans=input.split("to");

        for(String result:ans) {
        System.out.println(result.trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Please check and let me know if it works fine for you.

Answer (score 8):

Using split:

```
    if (exp.contains(" to ")) {
        String[] numbers = exp.split(" to ");
        // convert string to numbers  
    }
```

Using regex:

```
    Matcher mat = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) to (\\d+)").matcher(exp);
    if (mat.find()) {
        String first = mat.group(1);
        String second = mat.group(2);
        // convert string to numbers
    }
```

Comment: Or even `if (exp.contains(" to "))`

Comment: Or `if (exp.matches("(\\d+) to (\\d+)")) {String[] res = exp.split(" to ")}` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code it would work for any string.

```
String test="7 to 10";
String tok[]=test.split(" (\\w+) ");
for(String i:tok){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output :**

```
7
10
```